# Recursive Properties As They Relate To Domains

Tags: logic

I'm struggling with understanding what restrictions recursive properties generally place on domains. also on a more global level I don't think I fully understand how functions are described in symbolic logic.

I hope these two examples will illustrate these issues:

1. Say there's a function $g:N \rightarrow N$ that satisfies the
   recursive property $g(n+1) = 7n + 2g(n)$ $\forall n \in N$

   My first question is this: Let's say I define a new function $g(n) =
       n^2 + 5n + 2$. What's the difference between $g(n)$ and the $g$ I
   described earlier? If I went on and described another $g(n)$ as
   being $g(n) = 10n$, what claim would I be making about both $g(n) =
       n^2 + 5n + 2$ and $g(n) = 10n$? Is this allowed? Are they the same?
   Are they different?
2. Finally, if I stated that $g(n) = 10n $ holds true for $\forall n
       \in N$, would I be making the following claim?

   $\forall n \in N, g(n) = 10(n) \Rightarrow g(n+1) = 7n + 2g(n)$

   or would I be making the following claim?

   $\forall n \in N, g(n) = 10(n) \Leftrightarrow g(n+1) = 7n + 2g(n)$

Comment: I think you have to specify the deduction system and axioms your logic consists of. For example, are you working in first-order or second-order logic? That makes a huge difference when it comes to recursion and induction, because second-order systems allow for more powerfull definitions of these...

Comment: We only just started, and I'm a novice in these matters, so I'm not too sure what deduction system we're using. But if I had to guess I'd say first-order logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, firstly, when you want to define a new function PLEASE use a new symbol, especially when you go on to reference both.

So I am going to say $f(n+1)=7n+2f(n), g(n)=n^2+5n+2, h(n)=10n$.

Now $$g(n+1)=(n+1)^2+5(n+1)+2=n^2+2n+1+5n+5+2=n^2+5n+2+2n+6=g(n)+2n+6$$

So firstly $g$ does not satisfy the recurrence relation for $f$. Also notice at this point that we know precisely what function $g$ is, i.e. on input $n$ we can work out $g(n)$. However we don't know how to calculate $f$, we only know how to calculate it if we know smaller values, which we don't. So the recursive relation which $f$ satisfies does not uniquely specify the function $f$, we need to specify $f(0)$.

To illustrate if we have a function $i(n)$ which satisfies $i(n)=i(n)+2n+6$ do we know that $i=g$?

I don't really know what you are getting at regarding $h$, certainly $g$ and $h$ are different functions, for instance $g(0)=2$ and $h(0)=0$.

For two you are getting really confused, sentences are false as $g(0)=10(0)=0$ yet $g(1)\neq 7 + 0$.

Comment: 'So the recursive relation which f satisfies does not uniquely specify the function f, we need to specify f(0).' can you elaborate more on this? I think this is they key bit that's going over my head.

Comment: Ok lets take a basic example, suppose $f$ satisfies $f(n+1)=f(n)+1$. Now if I ask you "what is $f(3)$?" then using your recursive definition you can work out $f(3)=f(2)+1=f(1)+2=f(0)+3$, and now you are stuck. You can't go down anymore as $0$ is the smallest number, but you don't know what $f(0)$ is! So if I told you that $f(0)=3$ then you know that $f(3)=6$, however if I told you $f(0)=0$, then $f(3)=3$.

Notice that these are all consistent with the recurrence relation, so when you want to define a function by recursion you have to give the recurrence relation and an initial value.

Comment: Now I get it! So anytime I want to define a function through recursion I have to give at minimum: 1) a recurrence relation and 2) an initial value. the value I have to supply is that of $f(0)$ since all other values hinge on it. the beauty of recursion is that once you provide these two elements, everything else sorts itself out. quality explanation. thanks a ton!!

Comment: Glad to help, have fun with the halting problem.